# vba, simulations and arrays

Tags: vba, performance, multidimensional-array

I'm rather new to programming, and I am trying to determine if the following simulation is feasible in VBA:  A monte carlo simulation that involves 36 time periods, 20 simulation variables per period, and up to 5000 simulations per period.  The results of the simulations are then aggregated for each period to create 36 distributions (one per period).  This appears to be a 3d array that has to store variables, requires looping...etc.  I'm worried about computation time. Seems like this may be too much for vba to handle, so I wanted to get some feedback.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: YES it is feasible in VBA, go for it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is quite feasible. I do such things all the time.

When I first started using VBA 15-20 years ago, performance was often an issue, and it is still an issue for certain things. But by the magic of [Moore's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore's_law), VBA on my 2+ year old laptop matches the speed of compiled C 20 years ago:

```
Sub quick()
    Dim i As Long, sum As Long
    Dim start As Double, elapsed As Double
    start = Timer
    For i = 1 To 100000000
        sum = sum + 1
    Next i
    elapsed = Timer - start
    Debug.Print "Sum of " & sum & " computed in " & elapsed & " seconds"
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Sum of 100000000 computed in 0.765625 seconds
```

100 million passes through a loop in less than a second. Even if a simulation requires in the low billions of floating point operations, it might run in less than a minute. Unless each of those 5000 individual simulation steps of yours require hundreds of millions of computations, you should be fine.

So -- start coding. If you get stuck, post another question.

A word of warning: VBA is fast. Excel itself is fast. The bridge that links the two (the Excel Object Model) is slow. To get acceptable speed you should minimize transfer of data between the worksheet and VBA. A common beginner mistake is to use the spreadsheet itself as a data structure. Write the simulation itself in pure VBA with interaction with the spreadsheet largely confined to reading initial values at the beginning of the simulation and writing the output to the spreadsheet at the end.